What is the difference between a domestic lobbying group representing American supporters of a foreign country and an agent lobbying for that country?
I just came across this AIPAC's post by their account on X:

All 90 AIPAC-endorsed Democrats have won their primaries so far this
cycle!
Being pro-Israel is good policy and good politics!

My understanding of FARA (Foreign Agents Registration Act) is that it requires agents of foreign countries to disclose their relationship with the foreign government, as well as their activities, finances, and compensation, but AIPAC isn't registered.
AIPAC's activities strongly align with the interests of the Israeli government, for example:

Lobbying for U.S. Military Aid to Israel.
Support for Israeli Security Measures
Pushing Anti-BDS Legislations (Boycott, Divestment, and Sanctions movement against Israel)
Promoting Pro-Israel Resolutions
Influence on U.S. Middle East Policy
Strengthening U.S.-Israel Economic Ties

These activities illustrate how AIPAC's efforts frequently align with the strategic and policy objectives of the Israeli government, contributing to the perception that AIPAC functions in a capacity similar to a foreign agent by influencing U.S. foreign policy in favor of Israel.
But AIPAC claims that it is a domestic lobbying group representing American supporters of Israel, rather than acting as an agent of the Israeli government.
Based on this logic, if a domestic lobbying group existed in the USA to represent American supporters of Iran, would that be ok then?
If yes, then what is the difference between this and an agent directly lobbying for the foreign country if the actual outcome is exactly the same?
No country who is interested in influencing US politics would choose the FARA route, making it a pointless act.

With regard to the part about Iran, the Iranian equivalent would be NIAC Action and its associated political action committee. It is not as influential as AIPAC—though perhaps more due to Americans being not very pro-Iran—but nor is it marginal: like AIPAC, it has had major US politicians as speakers at its gatherings, including individuals such as Dianne Feinstein and Ro Khanna. It has benefitted from the same lax FARA enforcement as AIPAC, and has been subject to similar accusations of being a foreign agent.

@Obie2.0 Then what is the point of having FARA if AIPAC and NIAC Action can deliver the same results they want without registering?

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/87784/whats-the-point-of-israel-doing-some-astroturfing-in-the-us-when-there-are-ple

Based on this logic, if a domestic lobbying group existed in the USA to represent American supporters of Iran, would that be ok then? - FYI: National Iranian American Council For more ethnic lobbying groups in the US see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_interest_groups_in_the_United_States#Most_recognized_ethnic_interest_groups

@Morisco This was already mentioned in the comments above. Thanks anyway.

It was mentioned, but the question still contains incorrect claims, like the one I quoted above.

It comes down to who is doing the funding and if that funding is coming from domestic sources or foreign sources.

The Foreign Agents Registration Act (FARA) (22 U.S.C. § 611 et seq.)
is a United States law that imposes public disclosure obligations on
persons representing foreign interests.[1][2] It requires "foreign
agents"—defined as individuals or entities engaged in domestic
lobbying or advocacy for foreign governments, organizations, or
persons ("foreign principals")—to register with the Department of
Justice (DOJ) and disclose their relationship, activities, and related
financial compensation.[2]
FARA does not prohibit lobbying for foreign interests, nor does it ban
or restrict any specific activities.[3] Its explicit purpose is to
promote transparency with respect to foreign influence over American
public opinion, policy, and laws; to that end, the DOJ is required to
make such information publicly available.[4] FARA was enacted in 1938
primarily to counter Nazi propaganda,[5][6] with an initial focus on
criminal prosecution of subversive activities; since 1966, enforcement
has shifted mostly to civil penalties and voluntary compliance.[7]

If you look at the part I bolded it is the requirement that people who are working with foreign actors and/or receiving money from those sources are the ones who need to require. In this case AIPAC is likely claiming to be domestic because they are not directly working with foreign actors or receiving funding from them as part of their operation and all of that is from domestic sources. While they do align in their goals and objectives that doesn't mean that they are actively working with them.
From what I can see it was originally founded by a lobbyist for the Israeli government but the ties have seem to shifted since then
AIPAC

AIPAC was founded in 1954 by Isaiah L. Kenen, a lobbyist for the
Israeli government,[7][8] partly to counter negative international
reactions to Israel's Qibya massacre of Palestinian villagers that
year.[9] AIPAC only became a powerful organization during its peak
influence in the 1980s.[10] In 2002, AIPAC expressed intent to lobby
Congress to authorize use of force in Iraq,[11] and in 2003, the Iraq
War was defended at AIPAC events.[12][13][14] In 2005, a Pentagon
analyst pleaded guilty to espionage charges of passing U.S. government
secrets to senior AIPAC officials, in what became known as the AIPAC
espionage scandal.[15]


Worth noting, though, is that AIPAC's predecessor organization, which had a closer financial connection to Israel—it was part of an organization headquartered in Jerusalem, which counted as a foreign principal—at one point was asked to register at one point, and there have been periodic assertions from various individuals that coordination between AIPAC and successive Israeli administrations rises to the level of requiring FARA registration, including a lawsuit. But the basic that merely advocating for the "interests" of a foreign country is not enough is correct.

@Obie2.0 I will update the answer when I can

Was there an investigation and confirmation of the source of funding of AIPAC?
